Upload image to api with bio in flutter
In my flutter code. I'm using this method to upload the image:
  Future<Either<Failure, String>> uploadImage({required File image}) async {
    final String? accessToken = await secureStorage!.read(key: "access_token");

    return _tokenHandler.executeWithToken(
      apiCall: () async {
        var response = await _apiHelper.uploadFile(
          endPoint: "/upload/image",
          file: image,
          bodyKey: 'image',
          fileName: image.path.split("/").last,
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer $accessToken",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            "Accept": "*/*"
          },
        );
        return response["image"];
      },
    );
  }

and here is the api upload file function:
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> uploadFile({
    required String endPoint,
    required File file,
    required String bodyKey,
    required String fileName,
    Map<String, dynamic>? headers,
  }) async {
    log("file:$fileName");
    var response = await _dio.post(
      '$_baseUrl$endPoint',
      data: FormData.fromMap({
        bodyKey: await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          file.path,
          filename: fileName,
        )
      }),
      options: Options(
        headers: headers,
      ),
    );
    return response.data;
  }

I got this api error message "only images allowed" and here is the full api response:
{
    "message": "only images allowed",
    "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
    "statusCode": 422
}

put when I try post man it works fine and give me this repose:
{
    "message": "only images allowed",
    "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
    "statusCode": 422
}

I tried this method from Ai :
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> uploadFile({
  required String endPoint,
  required File file,
  required String bodyKey,
  required String fileName,
  Map<String, dynamic>? headers,
}) async {
  // Detect MIME type
  final mimeType = lookupMimeType(file.path);
  
  if (mimeType == null || !mimeType.startsWith('image/')) {
    throw Exception('Invalid file type. Only images are allowed.');
  }

  // Convert MIME type string to DioMediaType
  final mediaType = MediaType.parse(mimeType);

  var response = await _dio.post(
    '$_baseUrl$endPoint',
    data: FormData.fromMap({
      bodyKey: await MultipartFile.fromFile(
        file.path,
        filename: fileName,
        contentType: mediaType,  // Use DioMediaType
      )
    }),
    options: Options(
      headers: headers,
      contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
  );
  return response.data;
}

and it doesn't work for me. the file path:
her sis the log:
[log] file:image_cropper_1735085618268.jpg
[log] file_path:/data/user/0/com.example.todo/cache/image_cropper_1735085618268.jpg
D/EGL_emulation( 5121): app_time_stats: avg=2308.98ms min=2308.98ms max=2308.98ms count=1
[log] add_new_task_body - AddNewTaskFailure:only images allowed

this is all information I got
